# Insert from textbox into multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery

I am trying to insert a value from a text box into multiple selects, I have inserted into one of them, but I am unsure on how to insert into two.

My code. 
https://jsfiddle.net/neilcosby123/xazyfej3/

```
<input type="text" name="region" id="txt_RegionName" />
<br />
<input type="button" name="add" id="btn_AddToList" value="add" class="btn btn-success" />
<br />
<select size="10" id="lst_Regions" style="width: 500px;"></select>
<select size="10" id="2nd_Regions" style="width: 500px;"></select>
```

jQuery

```
$('#btn_AddToList').click(function () {
    var val = $('#txt_RegionName').val();
    $('#lst_Regions').append('<option>' + val + '</option>');
    $('#2nd_Regions').append('<option>' + val + '</option>');
    $('#txt_RegionName').val('').focus();
})
```

EDIT: The above code is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fix the typo its `#2nd` not `#nd`

```
$('#btn_AddToList').click(function () {
    var val = $('#txt_RegionName').val();
    $('#lst_Regions,#2nd_Regions').append('<option>' + val + '</option>');
    $('#txt_RegionName').val('').focus();
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xazyfej3/1/)

Comment: Wow, sometimes every day seems like Monday. Thanks for pointing that out.